# Decoding Bit Rate Information for an LED Project Using a Logic Analyzer

Tags: decoder, logic-analyzer

I am currently working on a project where I'm trying to understand and decode the bit rate information being sent to an LED. I purchased an LED for my backyard that can be changed to different colors but I'm limited to what the remote can do. If the LEDs are able to be RGB, which they are, I would like to be able to change them to any colors I would like if it is an addressable LED system. From my testing of the remote, it does seem that there are some addressable factors. Here's a summary of my progress and challenges:

[image]
[image]

**Project Description:**

**I have three main components in play:**

1. A remote control that sends an unknown signals.
2. A controller board which receives these signals. I have identified the chip on this board responsible for sending unknown codes to the LEDs (refer to the attached pictures for details).
3. An LED which seems to have both a board and a chip assigned to it. I'm unsure if this categorizes it as an addressable LED.

**What I've Done:**

I manually coded a sequence of 1's & 0's and created an Arduino program to send this sequence through a wire, which successfully turns the LED on and off.
I've researched all the chips associated with this project, but couldn't find any relevant information online.

**Challenges:**

1. I'm trying to understand the exact information being sent to the LED. While I can manually make the LED turn on/off using my Arduino setup, I'd like a clearer understanding of the underlying communication.
2. The presence of a board and a tip on the LED complicates the analysis as I'm unsure of their role in the system.

Decoded Message;

Red - 0000 0001 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010

```
 1           252           252           252
```

Green - 0000 0010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010

```
 2           252           252           252
```

Blue - 0000 0011 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010

```
 3           252           252           252
```

White - 0000 0100 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010

```
4           252           252           252
```

**My Question:**
How can I use a logic analyzer to decode the bit rate information being sent to the LED? Any guidance or recommendations to understand and interpret this data would be immensely appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148604/discussion-on-question-by-corbin-decoding-bit-rate-information-for-an-led-projec); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.